# Uri constructor

Tags: c#

Edit: I rephrase the question to make it clearer

I'm trying to understand what's the behavior of the Uri(Uri, uri) constructor:

```
 new Uri(new Uri("http://mydomain.com/some/path"), new Uri("/another/path"))
```

I get the following result:

```
 "http://mydomain.com/another/path"
```

But I cannot find any doc explaining clearly what the creation rules are.
In other words, is it guaranteed that i'll never get the following ?

```
 "http://mydomain.com/some/path/another/path"
```

unless I use as second parameter:

```
new Uri("another/path")
```

Comment: Do `new Uri("http://mydomain.com/some/path")` and `new Uri("/another/path")` *both* give you the result 
` "http://mydomain.com/another/path"`?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Each `new Uri` is independent from the other.

Comment: Hugo, you are missing one important detail: How do those two Uri instances interact with each other? Because just the code you showed doesn't result in one Uri that contains parts of both.

Comment: oups, sorry for that, I rephrased it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second `Uri`  `"/another/path"` is rooted (it starts with `/`), so the `Uri` created will have the domain followed by it.

If your second `Uri` were `"another/path"`, the result would be `"http://mydomain.com/some/path/another/path"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first Uri has to end with a '/'. The second one should have the leading '/' removed and be set to `UriKind.Relative`.

```
Uri a = new Uri("http://mydomain.com/some/path/");
Uri b = new Uri("another/path", UriKind.Relative);

Uri c = new Uri(a, b);

Console.WriteLine(c);
```

This will output:

> http://mydomain.com/some/path/another/path

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that first argument is the BASE and the second argument is the BASE-RELATIVE url.

Please look at the second one: it begins with a '/'. This means that the second one is ABSOLUTE, thus, only domainname is taken from the base, and the rest is taken literally.

If you want to make relative, then make it relative:

```
new Uri(new Uri("http://mydomain.com/some/path"), new Uri("another/path"))
```

please note that the leading / is missing now!